# How to query data between to dates having a timestamp field in the table?

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to fetch the customer details from the customer table in between two dates with BETWEEN CLAUSE : the datatype of the created_Date field is **timestamp** and the default value is **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**. I wrote the code like below:

```
SELECT membership_id FROM customers WHERE DATE_FORMAT( created_Date,
'%Y-%m-%d' ) BETWEEN '2016-05-07' AND '2016-06-08'
```

but even the above code not fetch data,

and when I do the below query

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE created_Date like'%2016-05-16%';
```

it works,

so from my knowledge there are some bug in **BETWEEN CLAUSE**.

anyone can help me?

Comment: I'm not sure how typecasting works in mysql, but you should probably use the `DATE()` function instead of `DATE_FORMAT()`; you need a date, not a string. If that doesn't work, you can also use the full timestamp, including the time, for the 2 dates you want to check.

Answer (score 2):

No need for any conversion. Keep the timestamp field as is and provide the date parameters as string literals

```
SELECT id,created_Date FROM customers
  WHERE created_Date BETWEEN '2016-05-07' AND '2016-05-08'
```

MySQL's type system can (and should) handle that.

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/691df/1

p.s.: The second parameter could be `'2016-05-08 23:59:59'` to include the whole may 8th.